# Why Netbeans IDE icons doesn’t work

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

I’m using Netbeans as my preferred IDE. I dont know exactly why such issue occur but when installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I use to set parameter, then installing JDK (1.8_u20), and Netbeans.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
sudo tar -xzf jdk...tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk... /opt/jdk
```

Then I use `gedit ~/.bashrc` to set PATH variables. ie

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

After closing gedit, run :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

And test java installation with `java --version` which normally should output JavaVirtualMachine (JVM) version informations. For example :

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

Netbeans installation can be done via...

```
./netbeans8.0.sh
```

or

```
./netbeans8.0.sh --javahome=/opt/jdk
```

I use to so install my IDE but last time I’ve reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, its appears that the icons used to represents `interfaces, abstract classes, enum and so on` doesn’t work. At the place, its use **class icons**. This is very confusing for me where eyes can not help me determine a file content.

Please how to solve it. Thanks.

Here is the **~/.netbeans/8.0/var/log/messages.log** content where I’ve replaced `/home/home_directory` by `$HOME`

---

```
>Log Session: Tuesday, December 23, 2014 2:29:55 PM WAT
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201403101706) (#b8e35b888b3f)
  Operating System        = Linux version 3.13.0-24-generic running on i386
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.8.0_20; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 25.20-b23; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_20-b26
  Java Home               = /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_US (nb); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = $HOME
  Current Directory       = $HOME
  User Directory          = $HOME/.netbeans/8.0
  Cache Directory         = $HOME/.cache/netbeans/8.0
  Installation            = $HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/ergonomics
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/ide
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/extide
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/java
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/apisupport
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/webcommon
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/websvccommon
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/enterprise
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/mobility
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/profiler
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/php
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/harness
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/cnd
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/dlight
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/groovy
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/javafx
                            $HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/classes:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
  Application Classpath   = $HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/boot.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/boot_pt_BR.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/boot_ru.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ru.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ru.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/lib/dt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/lib/tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = $HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/core/core.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/core/locale/core_pt_BR.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/core/locale/core_ru.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/core/locale/core_ja.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ru.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/core/locale/core_zh_CN.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb/core/org-netbeans-upgrader.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb/core/locale/core_nb_zh_CN.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_pt_BR.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb/core/locale/core_nb_ja.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb/core/locale/core_nb.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb/core/locale/core_nb_ru.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_ja.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb/core/locale/core_nb_pt_BR.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_zh_CN.jar:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_ru.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.structure which is deprecated.
Cannot initialize GTK colors - using hardcoded defaults: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthContext.getContext(java.lang.Class, javax.swing.JComponent, javax.swing.plaf.synth.Region, javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle, int)
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:
    org.openide.util.lookup [8.24.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.util [8.37.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.modules [7.42.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.api.annotations.common/1 [1.23.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.filesystems [8.10.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.awt [7.61.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.api.progress/1 [1.37.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.dialogs [7.36.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.nodes [7.38.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.windows [6.70.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup/1 [1.35.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.text [6.61.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.swing.tabcontrol [1.50.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.swing.outline [1.29.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.explorer [6.56.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.actions [6.34.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.queries/1 [1.38.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.loaders [7.56.2 201403101706]
    org.openide.io [1.44.1 201403101706]
    org.openide.execution [1.35.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.upgrader [4.30.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.swing.plaf [1.36.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 [1.57.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.swing.dirchooser [1.24.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.spi.viewmodel/2 [1.45.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.spi.tasklist/1 [1.29.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.spi.quicksearch [1.22.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.spi.palette/1 [1.41.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.spi.navigator/1 [1.32.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings/1 [1.52.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.util/1 [1.57.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.lexer/2 [1.58.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2/1 [1.84.1.43 43 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.keyring [1.19.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.bootstrap/1 [2.67.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.startup/1 [1.53.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.sampler [1.9.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core/2 [3.45.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.options.api/1 [1.39.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap [1.30.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage/1 [1.44.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.fold/1 [1.39.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent/2 [1.36.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib/3 [3.48.1.22.43 22 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0 [1.34.1.7.43 7 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi/1 [1.76.1.8 8 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.tools.storage [1.3.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.fold.nbui [1.6.1.43 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor/3 [1.78.1.5.22.43 5 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.options.editor/1 [1.50.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints.projects [1.6.1.1.7 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.api.debugger/1 [1.45.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui/1 [2.43.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.multiview/1 [1.39.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.api.xml/1 [1.38.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.core/2 [1.38.1.4 4 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.xam/1 [1.27.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.apache.xml.resolver [1.27.1.12 12 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.retriever/1 [1.26.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.schema.model/1 [1.27.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.axi [1.26.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.bracesmatching/0 [1.33.1.43 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting/0 [1.22.1.1.5.22.43 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.errorstripe.api/1 [2.28.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.api.java.classpath/1 [1.41.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.errorstripe/2 [2.29.1.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.diff/1 [1.46.1.42.1 42 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.guards/1 [1.25.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.project.indexingbridge [1.12.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.masterfs/2 [2.46.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.lucene/3 [3.15.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene/2 [2.27.2.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 [1.73.1.8 8 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.refactoring.api [1.39.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion/1 [1.39.1.2 2 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.codetemplates/1 [1.37.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.breadcrumbs/0 [1.11.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.ui/1 [1.40.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.api.search [1.16.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.jumpto/1 [1.41.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.actions/1 [1.25.1.43 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.csl.api/2 [2.46.1.2.1.1.8 2 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.structure/1 [1.42.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.lexer [1.25.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.text/2 [1.43.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml [1.26.2 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.servletapi/1 [1.35.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.httpserver/2 [2.31.1.42 42 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xsl/1 [1.38.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.xdm/1 [1.28.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.xerces/1 [1.34.1.281 281 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.tax/2 [1.38.1.281 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.tools/2 [1.38.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.schema.completion [1.25.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.xml.catalog/2 [1.36.1.4 4 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.execution/1 [1.36.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.sendopts/2 [2.30.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.favorites/1 [1.39.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.projectui [1.52.1.8 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.welcome/1 [1.37.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.json_simple/1 [0.8.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.web.webkit.debugging [1.31.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.web.common [1.68.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.web.indent [1.14.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.extexecution/2 [1.41.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.extbrowser/1 [1.47.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.settings/1 [1.44.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.windows/2 [2.75.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.web.browser.api [1.37.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.versioning.core/1 [1.20.1.1.42 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.versioning/1 [1.42.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.spellchecker.apimodule [1.20.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.versioning.util [1.57.1.42.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.team.commons [1.40.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.versioning.ui/1 [1.17.1.42.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.services [1.45.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.ui [1.40.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.versioning.system.cvss.installer [1.11.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.versioning.masterfs [1.9.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.versioning.indexingbridge/0 [1.20.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.utilities/1 [1.55.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.utilities.project/1 [1.33.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.javahelp/1 [2.36.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.usersguide/1 [1.44.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.updatecenters/1 [1.35.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.lib.uihandler [1.40.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.uihandler [2.30.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.uihandler.exceptionreporter [1.24.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.lib.terminalemulator [1.30.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.terminal [1.18.2 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.templates/1 [1.2.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.swingx/1 [1.23.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.team.ide [1.8.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.tasklist.ui/1 [1.26.1.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.tasklist.todo/1 [1.26.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.tasklist.projectint/1 [1.24.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.tasklist.kit [1.24.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.ini4j/1 [1.26.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.svnClientAdapter/1 [1.35.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.subversion [1.36.1.42.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.plain.lib/1 [1.29.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.spellchecker [1.30.1.1.7 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.spellchecker.kit [1.21.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.spellchecker.dictionary_en [1.18.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.properties/1 [1.49.2 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.properties.syntax/1 [1.45.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.spellchecker.bindings.properties [1.17.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.html.lexer/1 [1.34.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.spellchecker.bindings.htmlxml [1.22.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.ide/1 [1.36.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.server/0 [1.28.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.project.libraries/1 [1.46.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.project.ant/1 [1.59.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.progress.ui [1.28.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.print.editor [7.22.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.print [7.21.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.parsing.ui [1.9.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.notifications [1.3.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.osgi [1.17.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.netigso [1.26.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.netbinox [1.34.1 201403101706]
    org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net [3.10.0 3.10.0.20131018-1210]
    org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core [3.10.0 3.10.0.20131010-2023]
    org.eclipse.core.jobs [3.5.101 3.5.101.v20120113-1953]
    org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core [1.9.0 1.9.0.20131007-2055]
    org.netbeans.modules.bugtracking [1.101.1 201403101706]
    org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.6.0 3.6.0.v20110523]
    org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0 3.7.0.v20110110]
    org.netbeans.modules.mylyn.util [1.27.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.mercurial [1.36.1.42.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.nio2 [1.11.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.jna/1 [1.35.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.linux [1.9.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.bugtracking.commons [1.2.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.localtasks [1.20.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.localhistory [1.29.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.lexer.nbbridge/1 [1.27.1.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.bytelist/1 [0.23.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.jvyamlb/1 [0.25.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.languages.yaml [2.27.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.languages.manifest [1.27.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.languages.diff [1.28.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.keyring.fallback [1.3.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.keyring.impl [1.18.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.html.editor.lib/3 [3.26.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.antlr3.runtime [1.17.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.css.lib/1 [1.69.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.css.model [1.26.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.css.editor/1 [1.60.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.html/1 [1.55.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.html.editor/2 [2.48.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.nashorn/1 [1.15.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor/1 [0.36.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.knockout [1.3.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.extjs [1.3.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jquery [1.3.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.kit/1 [0.8.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.image/1 [1.43.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.multitabs/1 [1.7.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.bookmarks/1 [1.32.1 201403101706]
    com.jcraft.jsch [0.1.49 0.1.49]
    org.netbeans.modules.dlight.nativeexecution [1.33.3.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.dlight.terminal [1.18.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.multitabs.project [1.5.1.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.search [1.17.1.0.43 0 201403101706]
    org.apache.commons.logging [1.1.1 1.1.1]
    org.netbeans.modules.html.parser/1 [1.28.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.html.validation/1 [1.25.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.output2/1 [1.36.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.css.visual/3 [3.26.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.kit [1.28.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.cli [1.8.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.felix [2.11.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.core.kit [1.25.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.defaults/1 [1.27.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.macros/0 [1.26.1.1.22 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.plain/2 [1.30.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit [1.28.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.ide.ergonomics [1.24.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.pluginimporter [1.15.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.deadlock.detector [1.1.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.ide.branding/1 [1.28.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.ide.branding.kit [1.24.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner/1 [1.42.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.commons_net/2 [2.16.1.33 33 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.hudson [2.5.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.hudson.ui [1.5.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.hudson.tasklist [1.12.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.hudson.subversion [1.24.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.hudson.mercurial [1.24.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.hudson.git [1.13.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.html.knockout [1.5.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.html.custom [1.1.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.browser/1 [1.23.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.html.angular [1.6.1 201403101706]
    org.eclipse.jgit [3.2.0 3.2.0.201312181205-r]
    org.netbeans.libs.jna.platform/1 [1.5.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.jsch.agentproxy/1 [0.7.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.git/1 [1.19.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.git [1.14.1.1 201403101706]
    org.apache.commons.io [1.4 1.4]
    org.netbeans.modules.extexecution.impl [1.20.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup.impl/1 [1.26.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent.project/0 [1.17.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.global.format/1 [1.10.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.metadata.model/1 [1.6.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.db/1 [1.60.1.30 30 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.dbapi [1.29.1.30 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.derby [1.35.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.api.visual [2.42.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.sql.visualeditor/1 [2.26.1.30 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.dataview [1.24.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.core [1.31.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.sql.editor [1.31.1.30 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.mysql [0.23.1.2 2 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.drivers [1.25.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.kit [1.26.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.css.prep [1.20.1 201403101706]
    org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core [3.10.0 3.10.0.20131024-1218]
    org.apache.commons.httpclient [3.1.0 3.1.0]
    org.netbeans.modules.bugzilla [1.71.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.bugzilla.exceptionreporter [1.19.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.modules.bugtracking.bridge [1.40.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.svnClientAdapter.svnkit/1 [1.20.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.svnClientAdapter.javahl/1 [1.19.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.javafx [2.3.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.libs.freemarker/1 [2.29.1.238 238 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.network [1.4.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.nativeaccess/1 [1.26.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.io.ui/1 [1.25.1 201403101706]
    org.netbeans.core.browser.webview/1 [1.10.1.1.1 1 201403101706]
    org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc [3.10.0 3.10.0.20130704-2116]
    org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core [1.2.0 1.2.0.20130704-2116]
    org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core [3.10.0 3.10.0.20130926-1710]
    org.eclipse.equinox.security [1.1.1 1.1.1.R37x_v20110822-1018]
    org.eclipse.equinox.registry [3.5.200 3.5.200.v20120522-1841]
    org.eclipse.equinox.preferences [3.4.2 3.4.2.v20120111-2020]
    org.eclipse.equinox.app [1.3.100 1.3.100.v20110321]
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth [3.2.200 3.2.200.v20110110]
    org.eclipse.core.net [1.2.100 1.2.100.I20110511-0800]
    org.eclipse.core.contenttype [3.4.100 3.4.100.v20110423-0524]
    org.apache.xmlrpc [3.0.0 3.0.0]
    org.apache.ws.commons.util [1.0.1 1.0.1]
    org.apache.commons.lang [2.4.0 2.4.0]
    org.apache.commons.codec [1.3.0 1.3.0]
    javaewah.dummy [0.5.6 0.5.6]
    com.jcraft.jzlib [1.0.7 1.0.7]
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.textile.core@1.9.0.20131007-2055 resolved
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.confluence.core@1.9.0.20131007-2055 resolved
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.8.0.v20120529-1548 started
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy resolver: Gnome
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.gnome.GsettingsNetworkProxy]: GSettings system proxy resolver: direct connection
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy reloading succeeded.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy - mode: direct
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy: fell to default (correct if direct mode went before)
Diagnostic information
Input arguments:
    -Djdk.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20
    -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=$HOME/.netbeans
    -Dnetbeans.running.environment=gnome
    -Dnetbeans.dirs=$HOME/netbeans-8.0/nb:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/ergonomics:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/ide:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/extide:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/java:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/apisupport:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/webcommon:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/websvccommon:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/enterprise:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/mobility:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/profiler:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/python:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/php:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/identity:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/harness:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/cnd:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/dlight:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/groovy:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/extra:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/javacard:$HOME/netbeans-8.0/javafx:
    -Dnetbeans.home=$HOME/netbeans-8.0/platform
    -Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade
    -Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense
    -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
    -Xmx782m
    -Xss2m
    -Xms32m
    -XX:PermSize=32m
    -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
    -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
    -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
    -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true
    -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
    -XX:HeapDumpPath=$HOME/.netbeans/8.0/var/log/heapdump.hprof
Compiler: HotSpot Client Compiler
Heap memory usage: initial 32.0MB maximum 755.9MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 160.0kB maximum -1b
Garbage collector: Copy (Collections=70 Total time spent=0s)
Garbage collector: MarkSweepCompact (Collections=3 Total time spent=0s)
Classes: loaded=6178 total loaded=6179 unloaded 1
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 4,101,120,000
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.DownloadListener]: Reading URL http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.0/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz?unique=NB_CND_EXTIDE_GFMOD_GROOVY_JAVA_MOB_PHP_TOMCAT_WEBCOMMON_WEBEE024bff764-4e60-469d-9bf3-c4a800575a1e_a37b556e-4e67-4087-a1f8-ab1810cbce09 failed (java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.netbeans.org)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.DownloadListener]: Reading URL http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.0/uc/final/certified/catalog.xml.gz?unique=NB_CND_EXTIDE_GFMOD_GROOVY_JAVA_MOB_PHP_TOMCAT_WEBCOMMON_WEBEE024bff764-4e60-469d-9bf3-c4a800575a1e_a37b556e-4e67-4087-a1f8-ab1810cbce09 failed (java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.netbeans.org)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.DownloadListener]: Reading URL http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/8.0/catalog.xml.gz failed (java.net.UnknownHostException: plugins.netbeans.org)
WARNING [org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager]: use of system property netbeans.home has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places at org.netbeans.Clusters.relativeDirsWithHome(Clusters.java:137)
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.8.0.v20120529-1548 256
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.8.0.v20120529-1548 stopped
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.8.0.v20120529-1548 stopped
```

Comment: do you see anything useful in logs ? if don't try reinstalling

Comment: Please, where to fing logs ?

Comment: Yes! I think I’ve found it at `~/.netbeans/8.0/var/log/messages.log`. Please, what should I done with.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can reinstall the JDK and netbean. Maybe with the version of the JDK.May have relationship and order of installation.

Comment: Netbeans can't be installed before JDK. I discovered later that it is related to Netbeans version (8.0) so ,I'm now using 8.1


, any way, thank you for paying attention.

Comment: I just saw the same thing happening on 8.0 for me. In this case I'm trying to run a Netbeans application and closes after starting.